# Navigation through multiple tabs for showing which is active class

Tags: jquery

I have 4 roles  for navigation which inside contains multiple tabs one of them is

```
<div class="tslcNav" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="mng.html">Manage</a></li>
            <li><a href="risk.html">Risk Assesment</a></li>
            <li><a href="security.html">Security Setup</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have written the code which shows which is active class in jquery as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
                .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $(".tslcNav ul li a").each(
                function() {
                    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl
                            || $(this).attr("href") == '')
                        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
                })
    });
</script>
```

How should I write the code if I index inside contains multiple tabs likewise other mng, risk and security contains multiple tabs.How should I write the code  to show which is active class in only one file to achieve code modularisation.

Answer (score 0):

as per your code, this will return any `active` class tab if it contains.

```
get_active = $("ul.nav li a.active");
```

you can modify it based on DOM structure...

Comment: Then where should I call that get_active??That means I have to edit whole function?

Comment: you shouldn't call `get_active` it will give you the current active tab DOM property. as per your query you want to get active tab right? it will give you active tab.. else modify or clarify your question properly